# Oracle field displays ??? instead of Russian letters

Tags: oracle, unicode

I run the follows to update the record

```
        update lims_min.languages
        set Apriori = 'Русский'
        where langid = 'RUS';
        COMMIT;
```

when I do select, I see the ???? instead of the correct word. Apriori is NVARCHAR2.

Is there another trick here?

Comment: Which client are you using, and what is its encoding set to?

Comment: may be you should check your `NLS_LANG` settings ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but is too long for a comment.

As already said you need to check NLS_LANG but also

- your database character sets
- what is the tool used to display data
- the platform used (Windows, Linux, ...)
- if you use Windows are you using a GUI program or a CLI program.

The following works on Linux CLI environment with SQLPlus:

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum=1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> host echo $NLS_LANG
American_America.UTF8

SQL> --
SQL> select parameter, value
  2  from nls_database_parameters
  3  where parameter like '%SET%';

PARAMETER              VALUE
------------------------------ --------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET           AL32UTF8

SQL> --
SQL> create table t(l varchar2(3), a nvarchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> --
SQL> insert into t values('RUS', 'Русский');

1 row created.

SQL> --
SQL> select * from t;

L     A
--------- ------------------------------
RUS       Русский

SQL>
```